# Is a software implementation of a PCP encoder available?

Tags: pcp

We all know the [PCP Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCP_theorem). Is there any software package availalbe taking a CNF in e.g. DIMACS format as input, and producing a PCP encoding in the same format as output? It might be interesting to run existing SAT solvers on such encoded instances and compare the performance relative to plain instances.

Answer (score 5):

There has been some recent effort to make PCPs practical for use in verifying outsourced computation. Check the work by this UT Austin group for example: http://www.cs.utexas.edu/pepper/.

Comment: (From what I can see, that work is "PCPs for succinct arguments" $\hspace{2.24 in}$ rather than "PCPs in their own right".) $\:$

Comment: succinct arguments are the goal of the work, i am not sure if they develop a general enough PCP encoder for OP's purposes on the way

Answer (score 5):

Eli Ben-Sasson's group is working on implementing PCPs. You can e-mail him and ask for their code.